# How to scale a sprite(2D) using a matrix

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I have a 2D tower defense game I'm making and I want my sprites to scale to the screen size. So someone suggested using a  matrix. So I tried to use one but I don't really know how to use it and how it works. So, how would I create a matrix and use it to scale 2D sprites in monogame. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can scale SpriteBatch using matrix, could be used to zoom in/out to affect whole screen.

```
ScalingFactor = new Vector3(widthScaling, heightScaling, 1);
Scale = Matrix.CreateScale(ScalingFactor);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null,null, Scale);
```

Comment: I'm using 2D sprites but im going to guess that the concept is the same

Comment: I used this code to get the screenscale but it says it is a null reference:                                               float screenscale = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1366f;                                                                 1366f is my screen size in pixels